# Display filter to see WPS attempts in WireShark

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

I have tried "WPS" and "eap.wps.code" and neither work.

This is a repost from the InfoSec SE:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221228/display-filter-to-see-wps-attempts-in-wireshark

as it has been put on hold there as being off-topic. I'm reposting the original below in its entirety in the interest of time saved in editing. As described below, my network was just now attacked.

My neighbour is actively trying WPS pins on my router - I know because the "WiFi/WPS" LED on my router lit up when I have permanently turned it off! I double checked the setting using the router admin page through ethernet and it confirmed LED's were off (except during WPS negotiation, which overrides the off setting). Note, it's a Tenda AC10 router.

Additionally all my 5Ghz devices got disconnected, I'm not sure if it's because of aggressive WPS packets or a simultaneous deauth flood was issued.

I need to track down the WPS packets and pin-point the MAC address the attempts were issued from. I tried using the "WPS" display filter in Wireshark as well as the "eap.wps.code" filter, no packets were found AS the packets were being recorded!

The same also occurred a couple of days back when I was trying WPS attempts against my own device and couldnt see the same frames with the "WPS" display filter in WiresharkI I dropped the issue since I had - in theory - disabled WPS on my AP's so considered it a smaller problem.

Please let me know the exact display filters to use to detect WPS pin attempts in some kind of a flood attack.

Comment: Here are the list of display filters for WPS in WireShark: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/w/wps.html

Comment: Yes I referred that document, but which specific keys should I use to see WPS connection _attempts_ specifically, say by brute-forcing several pins. This attack was going on for about 10-15 mins, so it must have been a brute-forcing attempt I think, rather than a small number of "leaked" keys that might have been tried using one of several WPS-cracking tools on Linux or Android.

Comment: If you know his MAC address, you could try `wlan.src = XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`<br>

Answer (score 0):

You could try these potential solutions:

**Method 1** - Catching MAC being used for WPS bruteforce: Capture packets to the access point: `wlan.dst = (AP Mac)` and exclude trusted devices if necessary: `wlan.dst = (AP Mac) and not wlan.src = (Trusted Mac) and not wlan.src = (Trusted Mac)`
 This takes into account that you are having issues using the WPS filter

**Method 2** - Detect DeAuth: I cannot access this website, but [here](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/detect-script-kiddie-wi-fi-jamming-with-wireshark-0186138/) is a tutorial on detecting a DeAuth flood. If that doesn't work, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/71cgvw/finding_physical_location_of_source_of_deauth/) is a tutorial from reddit to detect a DeAuth flood.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve made so many assumptions that are possibly wrong.

First, you won’t see any WiFi packets you are looking for unless you have a sophisticated enough WiFi adapter that can be put in to [monitor mode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode). Many adapters you find in your typical laptop will not do this, or will not do it well. Or will only work in one OS or another. Perhaps these packets simply don’t exist in the first place.

Second, according to the [manual](http://www.tenda.cz/sites/Upload/AC10/AC10_UG.pdf) on page 2, the WiFi / WPS light has four indications: solid = the 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz band is enabled. Fast blinking = data is being transmitted. Slow blinking = WPS negotiation . Off = WiFi disabled.  There is an option to turn off the lights. There is nothing in the manual that suggests it will turn on only with WPS negotiation.

Third, if you disabled WPS you’re making some serious assumptions suggesting that WPS is somehow still usable. If it was, it would most likely be because you pressed the WPS button on the back of the router at which time the light will flash for two minutes. If what you said was true it would be a firmware flaw not necessarily a hack attempt.

Fourth, there is no indication whether the WPS light flashes because of an attempt to connect or because you pushed the WPS button. There’s a good chance it would do absolutely nothing if someone was trying to connect. The light is more likely to help indicate the two minute window you have to connect a device after you push the WPS button and that is it.

Now, you have to consider that this is a $30 router with no US support. The most likely thing going on is that you are dealing with a firmware bug or the WPS switch is malfunctioning on the back of the router, or something sitting near the router is pushing the button. But, being you turned off WPS there is almost no chance someone is “hacking” your router. If they were, it’s probably the Chinese or Russians.

Prove my point. Turn WPS off and push the WPS button. Does the WPS light start flashing? Does it start flashing for 2 minutes then stop? Does it not respond at all? Or does it just keep on flashing? Is it a fast flash or a slow flash?

My bet is that the light isn’t on all the time but just occasionally slow flashes, and it always slow flashes for two minutes after you press the button. Or, it just stays on slow flashing all the time and the button does nothing. Both would be an indication to me that the WPS button is malfunctioning. Or, it isn’t even a slow flash and is completely unrelated to WPS.

Finally, there is a system log on the router. If there was any chance of finding clear, easily decipherable messages about what your router was doing it would be there.

There are so many real diagnostic steps you could take instead of immediately jumping to a conclusion that is almost certainly false.

Answer (score -1):

Check this filter that will indicate when WPS is started: eapol.type == 1

Comment: This is a really short answer, can you elaborate a little more?